# How can I put "paginate" method in my controller index function?

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I am going to put paginate method to view my data in my controller index function. I have been configured all things with paginate and but I am unable to guess where should I put following paginate in the index function,

```
paginate(10);
```

my index function,

```
public function index()
    {

        $vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')->get()->sort(function ($a, $b) {
        if ($a->adtype !== $b->adtype) {
            return $b->adtype - $a->adtype;
        }

        return $a->adtype
            ? ($a->updated_at->gt($b->updated_at) ? -1 : 1)
            : ($a->created_at->gt($b->created_at) ? -1 : 1);
    });

    return view('vehicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
    }
```

where should I put them?

**view**

@extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')
@forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )
           @if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
                        <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
                            @php
                                $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
                            @endphp

                            <div style="border-style: solid; color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'black' : 'blue' }} ">
                            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>


                        {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($vehicule->created_at)->diffForHumans()}} 
                            {{$vehicule->provincename}}
                          {{$vehicule->milage}}

                          </div>
<br>
<hr>
@endif

            @empty
                <td>No Advertisment to display.</td>
            @endforelse
</div>

</div>
</div>
{{$vehicule->links()}}  //paginate showing links
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `get()` method with `paginate()` like this

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')->paginate()->sort(function($a, $b) { return })
```

and write the rest of your code normally

Comment: I use this **{{$vehicule->links()}}** in blade file then I got this error with your answer **ErrorException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links() (View: C:\Users\root\Desktop\bomna\resources\views\vehicles\index.blade.php)**

Comment: you must use the `links()` method out of the loop on the collection itself like this `{{ $vehicles->links() }}`

Comment: would you show me your view code so I can help you better

Comment: don't use the single `$vehicule` variable because of two reasons 
first: it's not defined out of the loop
second: it's an object of type `Vehicle` not `Collection`
so replace it with the collection object `$vehicles` to be like this
`$vehicles->links()`

Comment: you can also refer to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) for more info about pagination

Comment: it is got this error **Method links does not exist. (View: C:\Users\root\Desktop\ddddd\resources\views\vehicles\index.blade.php)**

Comment: did you change your controller method to `paginate()`?

Comment: in your controller can you replace your return statement with this `return view('vehicles.index', compact('vehicles'));`